# Parse.com Form not sending information, submit error?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parse-platform

Just wondering if anyone knows why my form won't store the data in my parse database?

I think it might be to do with my submit button...

HTML 5 form, which is supposed to integrate with parse.com, sorry Javascript isn't my strongest language.

```
 <div class="register span5 offset3">
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <h2>Create an account <!--<span class="red"><strong>iAPP</strong></span>--></h2>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit" onclick="signUp();">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    function signUp() {

        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("firstname", firstname);
    user.set("lastname", lastname);
    user.set("username", username);
    user.set("password", password);
    user.set("email", mail);

        // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
    user.set("phone", "650-555-0000");

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    }
    }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: no error, the code just doesn't send to parse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try coupling your signUp function to the submit eventhandler:

```
<div class="register span5 offset3">
            <form id="signupForm">
                <h2>Create an account <!--<span class="red"><strong>iAPP</strong></span>--></h2>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    function signUp(e) {
       //preventDefault so the form doesnt reload the page
        e.preventDefault();

        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var mail = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var user = new Parse.User();
    user.set("firstname", firstname);
    user.set("lastname", lastname);
    user.set("username", username);
    user.set("password", password);
    user.set("email", mail);

        // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
    user.set("phone", "650-555-0000");

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    }
    }
    );

    document.getElementById('signupForm').addEventListener('submit', signUp);
</script>
```

What I have done here is couple the submit event of the form with id "signup" to the event "submit". So when your button is pressed it will trigger this event and the listener gets executed.

```
document.getElementById('signupForm').addEventListener('submit', signUp);
```

also be aware of the `e.preventDefault()` I have added at the top of your function to prevent pagereload (which is done by default on form submit)

Just check out the changes I've made

I hope it helps